# Is there a way to make a webrtc video recording work on a secured network with blocked ports?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5, webrtc, rfc5766turnserver

I read somewhere that the TURN server should be used for these kinds of scenario but it looks like this is just used for video conferencing/chatting type. In my case I only need to record a video in a browser. Is this something that a TURN server is still considered?

Any advice will be very much appreciated.

I already have a working video recording via browser.

I want to support those who are under a strict network with blocked port 80 and 443 and other necessary ports that the webrtc requires so they could still record a video on their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a web page with video recording only then you do not need WebRTC at all. The main purpose of WebRTC is for audio/video/data communications between peers.

What you are referring is just an access to your web page by HTTP (port 80) and by HTTPS (port 443). These two are main ports and usually they are open (at minimum 443). Otherwise the whole Internet and Intranet will be blocked. So there is no sense to care about it because it's not a normal situation and unlikely happen.